# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp (Access is denied)

Tags: java

When I upload files to local system's temp directory from Mozilla Browser I get Access denied error. But if I do the same thing from Eclipse Browser I dont see any error, means it is uploading without any error:

Code:

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
     fileName = getFileName(part);
     part.write(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + fileName);
}


private String getFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    System.out.println("content-disposition header= "+contentDisp);
    String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
        }
    }
    return "";
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp (Access is denied)
```

Allan, this is the code:

```
final String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
OutputStream out = null;
InputStream filecontent = null;
final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try {

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName = getFileName(part);

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path , fileName));
            filecontent = part.getInputStream();

            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            File UploadedFile = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);
            UploadedFile.delete();
       }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {

        writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                + "location.");


    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (filecontent != null) {
            filecontent.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876743/creating-file-on-windows-7-causes-access-denied-exception

Comment: Thanks Allan for providing the reference issue but my problem is, Its a web app so any one can use. How can any one get access permissions to users temp folder(as per the solution by Sircapsalot). If my understanding is incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: you can trie to create in another path using the class createTempDirectory.

Comment: File myTempDir = Files.createTempDir();

Comment: Tried with "File myTempDir = Files.createTempDir()", again I see the same error Access Denied

Comment: Allan: Tried with different paths. No result, got that same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example, when create the file use two parameter as the example:

```
File scratchFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "filename.tmp");
```

Example:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // Create path components to save the file
    final String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);

    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try {
        //File Temp here with two parameters
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path , "filename.tmp"));

        filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {

        writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                + "location.");
        writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (filecontent != null) {
            filecontent.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And your method:

```
private String getFileName(final Part part) {
      final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
      for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
          if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
              return content.substring(content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
          }
      }
      return null;
}
```

References:

[Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845045/permission-denied-when-writing-file-to-default-temp-directory)

[Upload Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)

Comment: Allan: Finally it worked. Thanks alot for taking time and given that code.

Comment: Allan: After writing the file in temp folder how to delete that file. I created a file object with the same file path and tried to delete with "fileobject.delete()". But the file was not deleted.

Comment: The file will deleted automatically when restart the computer.

Comment: No Allan, its not happening. The files are not deleted even after system restart.

Comment: Added Code in the question part. Please check.

Comment: Shekar i believe the path are you delete it's wrong, you can sure doing the test:
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
} else {
    System.err.println(
        "I cannot find '" + file + "' ('" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "')");
}

Comment: Strange! File delete code executed but file is still existing in the path. if(UploadedFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Deleting the file from the path-----" + UploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        UploadedFile.delete();
       }else {
        System.err.println( "I cannot find '" + UploadedFile + "' ('" + UploadedFile.getAbsolutePath() + "')");
       }.

Comment: close the FileOutputStream before delete.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a web application, the Webcontainer might have set some SecurityManager (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) to block write access to the local file system. 
Check if this has been the case...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I was facing few minutes ago.
Your code won't work for file upload with other request parameter together.

when you're calling **getParts()** it takes other parameters also as parts.

1. Now in case of file taken as part content-dipsosition header has

**form-data; name="`<file-parameter-name>`"; filename="`<filename>`"**

> A thing to be noted `<filename>` may be different if submitted from
>   different browser. Try to submit it from eclipse's in built browser.
>   Try to print and see content-disposition header by
>   System.out.println(part.getHeader("content-disposition"));

2. In case of your loop runs for other parameters taken as part, content-disposition has

**form-data; name=""**

Now see there is nothing like filename="", so your function to get filename returns null.

Now you calls part.write() but inside only path is passed not filename as function you called to get filename returns null. So you get exception even thought it actually uploads file.

After getting filename put a condition

if(filename.equals("")){continue;}
But that's also not a good solution as loop iterate for no reason for other parameter.